# Use Angular Material 2 menu as contextual menu on list items

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to show a contextual menu when the user right-clicks an item in a list of alarms. The problem is I need to use the directive `mdMenuTriggerFor` to be able to call `openMenu()` from the component. But this directive is intended to work on left-click, so the menu is always shown (left & right click). Also, on right click, the menu is displayed at the top of the list.

My code looks like this:

```html
<div class="list">
    <div *ngFor="let alarm of (_alarms | alarmsFilter:search.value)">
        <alarm-item [alarm]="alarm" (onClick)="onSelection(alarm)" (contextmenu)="onContextMenu($event, alarm)" [mdMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu"></alarm-item>
    </div>
</div>

<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu">
    <!-- Menu content -->
</md-menu>
```

And my component typescript file looks like this:

```ts
@Component({
    selector: // My selector
    templateUrl: // My template URL
})
export class AlarmComponent {
    @Input() alarm;
    @ViewChild(MdMenuTrigger) trigger: MdMenuTrigger;

    // ...

    private onContextMenu($event: Event, alarm: Alarm): void {        
        this.trigger.openMenu();

        $event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found subclassing the MdMenuTrigger was a way to do it.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ctx-menu]',
  host: {
    'aria-haspopup': 'true',
    '(mousedown)': '_handleMousedown($event)',
    '(keydown)': '_handleKeydown($event)',
    '(click)': '_handleClick($event)',

  },exportAs:'ctxMenu'
})
export class CtxMenuTrigger extends MdMenuTrigger{

    @Input('For') // Route the menu to the superclasses menu
    get _ctxMenuFor(): MdMenuPanel {
        return this.menu;
    }
    set _ctxMenuFor(v: MdMenuPanel) {
        this.menu = v;
    }
    _handleClick(e){
        // absorb left click event
    }
    openCtxMenu(e){
        super._handleClick(e);
        // return false so contextmenu event stops the browsers rightclick menu
        return false
    }
}
```

Then its a case of declaring in your HTML

```
<div class="list">
    <div *ngFor="let alarm of (_alarms | alarmsFilter:search.value)">
        <alarm-item [alarm]="alarm" (onClick)="onSelection(alarm)" 
            #rclick=ctxMenu ctx-menu 
            [For]="appMenu"
            (contextmenu)="rclick.openCtxMenu()" 
        ></alarm-item>
    </div>
</div>

<md-menu #appMenu="mdMenu">
    ...
</md-menu>
```

Not sure if its especially elegant, but seems to work ok.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
   @Directive({
    selector: '[rightClickTrigger]',
    host: {
        'aria-haspopup': 'true',
        '(click)': '_handleClick($event)',
        '(contextmenu)': 'handleContext($event)',
    }
})
export class RightClickTrigger extends MdMenuTrigger{
    @Input('rightClickTrigger')
    get _menuFor(): MdMenuPanel{
        return this.menu;
    }
    set _menuFor(v: MdMenuPanel){
        this.menu = v;
    }
    _handleClick(e) {
        // left click
    }
    handleContext(e){
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the browsers context menu
        super._handleClick(e);
    }
}
```

And then in HTML

```
<some-item [rightClickTrigger]="someMenu"></some-item>

<md-menu #someMenu>
 ....
</md-menu>
```